# Change theme in Chrome to one that's been previously installed

Tags: google-chrome, themes

This seems like it should be really easy to do, I just can't work out how.

Is there a way in Chrome to switch to themes that have previously been installed on the browser. Themes that have been installed through the Market Place.

If you install a theme through the Market Place, a file downloads, installs itself, then disappears. If you revisit that theme page, you're told it's already installed, even if you have installed a different theme in the intervening time.

I can find no interface within the latest version of Chrome (11, I think) that allows you to reselect that theme. Is there one?

Comment: Far as I know, there isn't one yet.

Comment: Nah; while you can have plenty of extensions installed, you can only have one theme at a time (even though themes are stored and handled the same way as extensions). Every time you install a theme, it wipes out and replaces your previous one.

Comment: ...still sucks like this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is not a way to install a previously-used theme from your own system. (Though I imagine a genius programmer can find a way to play with it.)

The Web Store should not be saying it is already installed - it only says that for currently installed extensions, not extensions that were installed at some time. Try refreshing the page. Then try removing cookies and / or temporary files, and then refreshing the page.

Comment: I actually rebooted the machine for other reasons. But the affect was the same. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 16):

I ran into much of the same trouble trying to switch back to a previously-used theme in later versions of Google Chrome.  I'm not usually one to plug an addon unless it really works for me.  The only thing I found that worked is the Chrome extenstion [Extensions Manager (aka Switcher)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc).

It showed me the themes I had previously installed and allowed me to switch back to them.  At very least it did a proper job of uninstalling the theme so that I could actually go back to the Chrome Web Store and re-download the one I wanted to use again.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to switch betwen installed themes. It's strange that chrome doesn't have this nativaly, or maybe it exists but we couldn't find easily.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as Extensions Manager is the simplest way to do this (amazingly enough).  Due to the Chrome 69 re-design, I have had to install the Pro  Grey theme just to make the non-selected tabs properly visible on Mac, and this tip was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

1) Go to the previously downloaded theme on the extensions page (it shows as installed with a RATE IT button)

2) Click the share link. Share via GMAIL.

3) A compose window will open with a text message like this:

Check out "bloomind ct deepdark": https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bloomind-ct-deepdark/djolekdiiojehgfggcjckachfgkkdmjd?utm_source=gmail

4) Delete the folder in your google-chrome/Default directory named "djolekdiiojehgfggcjckachfgkkdmjd" (citing the example above).

5) Restart the broswer. You can now re-download the theme from the extensions page.

Kludgy, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings, reset to default theme. Afterwards you can reinstall any theme you previously installed.

Comment: This doesn't work, I tried it on Chrome 69 and the previously installed theme can't be re-installed as the "Added to Chrome" button replaces the "Add to Chrome" one.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the "theme" section in the marketplace a window will pop up with a preview of what it will look like on your browser.

At the top of the window there is a little banner that says this item has been disabled in Chrome then there is a blue hyperlink that says "enable it." Click the link and you're in business.

Comment: There is no such banner.

Comment: this suggestion worked for me in Chrome 49 on OS X